# How to get code coverage for Async methods, when using .Net Framework and Azure pipelines VSTest@2 task

Tags: azure-devops, .net-framework-version

I have a task for unit test and code coverage, something like:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
  ...
  codeCoverageEnabled: true
```

The task seems to run ok, it executes all available unit tests, but when producing the code coverage report the async methods are ignored.
For example a new async method that has not unit tests covering it will not be higlighted as not cover. This is important because we have a policy
that requires that our code is cover with unit tests and when is not the pipeline should fail.

This is only happening in our .Net Framework 4.8 project, but not on our .NET Core ones (they use different pipeline task).

I've searched on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vstest-v2?view=azure-pipelines but couldn't identify a configuration setting that could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2022#example-runsettings-file--
and decided to try it out.

I modified my task by adding a runSettingsFile setting and added the related .runsettings file(I copied the example one from Microsoft page)

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
  ...
  codeCoverageEnabled: true
  runSettingsFile: 'CodeCoverage.runsettings'
```

And it solved the issue.

I suspect that there may be a way to do it without using an extra file but I'm ok with having a solution.